# Server responded with unhandled status: 400 ,on wget-improved in nodejs

Tags: node.js, npm, wget

On trying `'wget-improved'` module on `node.js` ,i get  `Server responded with unhandled status: 400` on the on error function

here fileToDownload, fileUrl be 'public/assets/

```
var wget = require('wget-improved');
var options = {
    protocol: 'http',
    headers :{'User-Agent': 'Node'},
    method: 'GET'
};

 var download = wget.download(fileToDownload, fileUrl, options);

    download.on('error', function(err) {

        console.log("error download");
        console.log(err);
                    var data = {
                        "CODE": 0,
                        "error": "error download"
                    }

        return;

    });

    download.on('start', function(fileSize) {
        console.log("file downloaded ")
        console.log(fileSize);

    });

    download.on('end', function(output) {
        console.log(output);
        var data = {
             "CODE": 1
          };


        return;


    });
    download.on('progress', function(progress) {
        // code to show progress bar


    });`
```

Comment: `public/assets/` isn't a valid URL.

Comment: yes its a valid one :)

Comment: As first or as second argument? It should be the first (and the second is the local path to where it should be saved).